# perform transformation on vector with if-condition in R

Tags: r, if-statement, transformation, regression

I am running regression models in R from PHP script. In fact, I am performing a regression...

```
fit <- lm(VIEWS ~ TREND + STUNDE + WOCHENTAG + MONAT * JAHR)
```

...then apply box-cox-transformation on the results, fetching the "best" lambda inside a range that makes sense in my case.

```
bc <- boxcox(fit, lambda = seq(0, 0.5, 0.005))
lambda <- bc$x[which.max(bc$y)]
```

If lamda is not 0, I apply the actual transformation and everything works fine:

```
VIEWS_BOX <- VIEWS^lambda - 1
```

I repeat the regression by replacing VIEWS by VIEWS_BOX.

My problem:
I need to write an if-condition for the case that lambda = 0, I read a lot and tried many things, but it just does not work. E.g. I tried:

```
VIEWS_BOX <- ifelse(rep(lambda = 0, length(VIEWS)), ln(VIEWS), VIEWS^lambda - 1)
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you used `lambda = 0`, but `=` means assignment. It should be `lambda == 0`, since `==` means comparison.

`ifelse` is not necessary. You can use:

```
VIEWS_BOX <- if (lambda) VIEWS^lambda - 1 else log(VIEWS)
```

Comment: Thanks for your support, Sven, but still it is not working, I tried `VIEWS_BOX <- if (lambda) VIEWS^lambda - 1 else ln(VIEWS)` and also `VIEWS_BOX <- if (lambda==0) ln(VIEWS) else VIEWS^lambda - 1`, but still the R execution stops at this line...!?

Comment: I found the solution: `VIEWS_BOX <- if (lambda==0) log(VIEWS) else VIEWS^lambda - 1` works fine, there is just no function `ln(x)` in R: `log(x)` returns the natural logarithm!

Comment: @bezoo Right. I just adopted your code and assumed you have created an `ln` function.